# How do I make weighed average (using alhpa channel as weight) of pictures?

Tags: imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I have multiple similar pictures I want to make aveage of, but not uniformatically. Each zone in pictures should have separate weight, and the weight is encoded in alhpa channel (fully transparent - zero weight, fully opaque - unit weight).

How to do it from command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it's something like this:

```
convert input1.png input2.png -channel RGB \
    -fx '(u[0]*u[0].a + u[1]*u[1].a) / (u[0].a + u[1].a)' \
    output.png
```